# ng-swipe-down and ng-swipe-up not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, swipe

I am trying to utilize (https://github.com/marmorkuchen-net/angular-swipe) in order to call a function when I swipe down, however, it is not working. I followed the directions provided by the README and I can see that I even have 'angular-swipe' in my bower_components. How do I go about fixing this?

Here is how I am calling ng-swipe-down

```
<div ng-swipe-left="nextImg()" ng-swipe-right="previousImg()" ng-swipe-down="dismissImg()" class="modal-content">
```

The `ng-swipe-left` and `ng-swipe-right` work fine. In my dismissImg() I just have an alert() to test.

```
$scope.dismissImg = function() {
        //jQuery to press a esc key
        alert("TESTING");
};
```

Comment: Have you listed the module `swipe` as adependency in your app definision?

Comment: Hi PSL, are you asking about my bower.json file dependencies or some other one? I have only changed the bower.json dependencies.

Comment: You would need to add it in the angular app declaration as well. SInce it is an angular module that you are going to use

Comment: Thanks for your reply PSL. I'm fairly new to angularjs app development. When you say 'angular app declaration' do you mean the `angular.module('myApp', [...])` in my app.js? If so how do I add it? I tried inserting `"angular-swipe":  "https://github.com/marmorkuchen-net/angular-swipe.git"` to the last location of the array but it gave me error.

Comment: `angular.module('myApp', ['anydependenciesyouhave','swipe'])..`

Answer (score 5):

Angular doesn't provide `ng-swipe-down` or `ng-swipe-up` directives. Not sure why. (Perhaps because it's too difficult to disentangle swiping from scrolling?) You can double-check this at any time in the [ngTouch Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch).

You've found the best solution I know for this: the [angular-swipe](https://github.com/marmorkuchen-net/angular-swipe) library, which exists solely to perform this exact function, adding up and down options to ngTouch:

```
bower install --save 'angular-swipe'
```

But it's not working for you. Probably because `swipe` is not listed as an Angular dependency, in this format:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['anydependenciesyouhave','swipe'])
```